# .got.plt not loaded into memory

Tags: virtual-memory, elf

I have an aarch64 process (`cat`) running on an Android (8).  I notice this section in `/proc/<PID/maps`:

```
746f308000-746f3de000 r-xp 00000000 103:00 5402    /system/lib64/libc++.so
746f3de000-746f3df000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
746f3df000-746f3e7000 r--p 000d6000 103:00 5402    /system/lib64/libc++.so
746f3e7000-746f3e8000 rw-p 000d3000 103:00 5402    /system/lib64/libc++.so
746f3e8000-746f3eb000 rw-p 000de000 103:00 5402    [anon:.bss]
746f40e000- ... next file
```

Here's the program header table for `libc++.so`:

```
Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000009040 0x0000000000009040 0x0001c0 0x0001c0 R   0x8
LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000009000 0x0000000000009000 0x0d58fc 0x0d58fc R E 0x1000
LOAD           0x0d68e0 0x00000000000e08e0 0x00000000000e08e0 0x007770 0x00aea8 RW  0x1000
DYNAMIC        0x0dbb40 0x00000000000e5b40 0x00000000000e5b40 0x000220 0x000220 RW  0x8
NOTE           0x000200 0x0000000000009200 0x0000000000009200 0x000038 0x000038 R   0x4
GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0d3058 0x00000000000dc058 0x00000000000dc058 0x0028a4 0x0028a4 R   0x4
GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0
GNU_RELRO      0x0d68e0 0x00000000000e08e0 0x00000000000e08e0 0x007720 0x007720 RW  0x10
```

Here's the section header for the `.got.plt`:

```
[Nr] Name        Type        Address          Off    Size   ES  Flg Lk  Inf Al
...
[22] .got.plt    PROGBITS    00000000000e6310 0dc310 001ce8 00  WA  0   0   8
```

Adding `0xe6310` to the base address, this section should be loaded at `0x746f3ee310`.  However, that lands between `[anon:.bss]` and the next file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `746f308000-746f3de000` mapping corresponds to the first `LOAD` segment, which defines a `0x9000` virtual address. Taking this into account, you must first calculate the address difference between the `.got.plt` section and the first segment, and add that difference to the mapped base address; this is equivalent to substracting the `0x9000` offset to your resulting address `0x746f3ee310`, that is `0x746f3e5310`, which is in the third mapping.